# Localization works during debug, fails upon setup

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, localization

I have a c# winform program which is translated to both Spanish and Portuguese. When debugging the program itself translates to the current windows chosen culture, and I also have a button to manually translate the program:

```
private void SetLanguage(string cul)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cul);
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control control in Controls)
    {
        var resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(FrmLogin));
        resources.ApplyResources(control, control.Name, new CultureInfo(cul));
    }
}
```

but when I install said application (with the Setup solution in visual studio) nothing works. The program loads default language (Spanish) and the button to manually translate doesn't work.

I'm using visual studio 2010. "Localizable" property is set to true.

Thanks!

Comment: During the setup, have you deployed satellite resources for both Spanish and Portuguese?

Comment: could you explain? The resources are located in the "view" Proyect (it's an MVC app). It follows the syntax FrmLogin.cs, Login.resx (Spanish) and Login.pt.resx (Portuguese). The setup only contains main output for the View project

Comment: double click the exe in the bin\Debug folder, is everything works fine? compare the files in the bin\Debug folder and the installation folder, I doubt that the resource files for Portuguese are missing.

Comment: found it! thanks :) I added the resources in the setup proyect and now it works (localized resources)